# Display clickable image URL through JEditorPane

Tags: html, url, jeditorpane

I'm making an HTML editor. When I do something like this:

```
<img src='File:///C:/User/Pictures/sample.jpg' alt='Smiley face'>
```

I'd like the JEditorPane to recognize the link and make it clickable so it opens in a browser. I don't, however, want the picture to actually show up in the pane. I just want the link to become clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the link to the picture use Photoshop, then you can click it.